# Rearrange toolbar items in eclipse. "New Android Project"

Tags: eclipse

General eclipse question.

In the toolbar > File > New > I have Java Project / Project/ a bunch of others / Others with sub menus for android.

How do I move the "New Android Project" to File > New > "Here"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not. The contents of that menu (and the toolbars) is dependent on the Perspective hat is currently active. If you change to another Perspective, you'll see it change. The items in the menus (and their grouping) are contributed by plugins; The Android ADT has contributed its menu items in the way you see; you can't change it.

If you work in the Java Perspective, you can right-click on an Android Project or a folder in a project and the New menu there has some of the Android-specific items at the top level.

Comment: Interesting.  The reason I ask is that we have to computers with the same version of Eclipse Indigo and Android ADT.  Yet my co-worker has it the way I want it.  He has no clue how or why it is set up that way.  Perhaps if I get time I will upload photos.